# windows 10 mobile wifi no connections available

Tags: windows-10-mobile, wifi

Me and my girlfriend both have a Lumia 735 running windows 10 mobile. My WiFi is working fine. However my girlfriend has the same problem every evening, being that the phone doesn't connect to any WiFi network anymore. When searching for networks, no networks are found. Rebooting the phone solves the issue. My sister has a Lumia 550, and has the exact same problem. Disabling and enabling WiFi again doesn't solve the issue. Are there more users with the same issue and is there any setting that fixes this? Apparently it doesn't happen to all phones because my phone doesn't have the issue.

Comment: i did get that issue in my 520 running on 10586.494, probably a bug!

Comment: I tried updating to the anniversary update, but this did not fix the issue. Ms support isn't very helpful either. They told me its not a known issue and it "might" be fixed it a future update.